# Calculating own index in ecognition

Tags: ecognition

I calculated two layers in ecognition. The Lee Sigma edge detection dark and bright. Now I want to make a summation of the dark and bright edges. How can I do this?

I then further want to use its to calculate different kinds of indexes (e.g. roughness). Is this possible in ecognition?